# "How to use argparse module and call the function from command line?"

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to use argparse in my code and call the function from the command prompt. But I don't know, how the argparse can be used? what should be there in my add-arguments in order to get my expected result?

I have tried to add arguments but getting the error. I am new to this. Can anyone help me and show how to format the code?

```
import argparse

for i in range(4):
    def func():
        global a
        a = 5
        print("today")
        print("yesterday")


    def func1():
        func()
        print(a)
        print('function 1')


parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument()
args = parser.parse_args()
```

my expected result is
today
yesterday
5
function 1
today
yesterday
5
function 1
today
yesterday
5
function 1
today
yesterday
5
function 1
Can anyone give me an example how to give command line values in python? and if i have some optional parameter in function how can i use argparse to make the function work from cmd?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need `argparse` unless your program has command-line arguments. You don't mention needing any.

Comment: I want to know how can I link argparse to this program to call the function from command prompt?

Comment: What is it that you're trying exactly to do? Why are you defining the functions in a loop?

Comment: `args` created by `parse_args` is a `Namespace` object.  Access to its attributes is well documented.  All it does it parse the command line.  It's up to your own code to use those values.  `argparse` is not a complete script runner.  But first, do you know how to provide command line values?